# making an array from other array items

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, mootools

I have the following problem:

```
var price   = ['4','5','8','12']
var produce = ['kiwi','orange','apple','banana']
var stock   = ['yes','no','no','yes']
```

i need to group them so that the end output is on array in the following format:

```
var store = [ ['4','kiwi','yes'],['5','orange','no'], ...]
```

im so confused as in how to make one array with these values into a 2d array. thanks

Comment: jquery and mootools? Why both? Do you know how to use a for loop? Do you know how to make a new array? Do you know how to use .push()?

Comment: epascarello. Jones seems to be a new user. Perhaps it is a little rude to slap him on the wrist like that on his first offence.. @jones: Please be more precise with your tags. Your question is not javascript framework centric. So it should only be tagged as javascript, not mootools and jquery.

Answer (score 3):

Using JavaScript with some overkill :):

```
var price   = ['4','5','8','12']
var produce = ['kiwi','orange','apple','banana']
var stock   = ['yes','no','no','yes']

// if the lengths/size of the above arrays are the same
var store = [];
for(var i = 0, len = price.length; i < len; i++) {
  store.push([price[i], produce[i], stock[i]]);
}

// if the lengths/size of the above arrays aren't the same and you want the minimum full entries
var storeMin = [];
for(var i = 0, len = Math.min(price.length, produce.length, stock.length); i < len; i++) {
    storeMin.push([price[i], produce[i], stock[i]]);
}

// if the lenghts/size of the above arrays aren't the same and you want the maximum entries with defaulting missing values to null 
// replace the nulls by any default value want for that column
var storeMax = [];
for(var i = 0, pLen = price.length, prLen = produce.length, sLen = stock.length, len = Math.max(pLen, prLen, sLen); i < len; i++) {
    storeMax.push([pLen>i?price[i]:null, prLen>i?produce[i]:null, sLen>i?stock[i]:null]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var price   = ['4','5','8','12']
var produce = ['kiwi','orange','apple','banana']
var stock   = ['yes','no','no','yes']
var store = [];
$.each(price,function(ind,elm) {
    store.push([elm,produce[ind],stock[ind]]);
});
console.log(store);
```

Comment: Well i need 15 points reputation to up vote you but, you're the man!

Comment: THANKS! i need reputation points to up vote, and i dont have them since this is new but thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, you can do it whenever you have those points. Anyway there are so many ways to do what you're trying to achieve and this is just one of them.

Comment: I think you have the best intentions jones. And welcome. I upvoted yoru reply so you get some rep to start with :) (which is actually constructive since it acknowledges the fact that inhan gave you the correct answer). I do believe you need to mark the question answered though :)